# Carbon\Carbon::now() throws InvalidArgumentException with message 'Trailing data'

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-artisan, php-carbon

When running the following in Laravel Artisan Tinker:

```
$article = new App\Article;
$article->published_at = Carbon\Carbon::now();
```

I get this error:

```
InvalidArgumentException with message 'Trailing data'
```

However, `Carbon\Carbon::now()` on it's own returns a `Carbon` instance as expected.

`published_at` should be mutated into Carbon instance via `protected $dates = ['published_at'];` in the model and it's also included in `protected $fillable`.

Anyone know what's going on here or how I can resolve?

---

EDIT: Same thing happens when ran in a closure in routes, so not specific to Tinker

EDIT 2: Looks like others are experiencing this: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/carboncarbonnow-giving-error and twice in comments for https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-fundamentals/episodes/8

EDIT 3: Pretty much exactly the same code as the first example is used in https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-fundamentals/episodes/15 at 15:10 without error.

EDIT 4: Swapping line 2 of the above code to `$article->published_at = Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d');` works fine and even includes time when stored in the database (although not sure why).

I'd guess that "trailing data" could refer to the full datetime being too long, but seems strange that Laravel does so much with datetimes automatically (auto-converting to Carbon instances, for example) but not this.

Usage in Edit 3 would be preferable though!

Comment: Looks like a regular DateTime error, however it shouldn't happen with `now()` method. Is there any chance something is wrong with your timezone settings? What does the timezone configuration look like in `config/app.php`?

Comment: Timezone is default:`'timezone' => 'UTC',`

Comment: By looking through the source code, it looks like it doesn't get past this line `return new DateTimeZone(date_default_timezone_get());` during class construction. If that doesn't lead you anywhere I doubt there is anything you can do except using native date functions.

Comment: Interesting — calling that separately works fine

Comment: Could it already be a Carbon instance?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel model Trailing Data when save the model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50208932/laravel-model-trailing-data-when-save-the-model)

Answer (score 2):

I've found that you should should not use `createFromFormat`, unless the second paramater `$date` is also a Carbon object, but if it's not and it's just a string you can just use

```
public function setPublishedAtAttribute($date){
    $this->attributes['published_at'] = Carbon::parse($date);
}
```

I think there's a little more overhead with regards to it having to figure out what format it's in, but this was my temporary workaround.

'Y-m-d' is the way the front parsed it into the form, but it's going into a database which is what Carbon spits out. I got the same error:

```
[2015-08-16 21:35:57] production.ERROR: exception 'InvalidArgumentException' with message 'Trailing data' in /Users/alexanderkleinhans/laravel/vendor/nesbot/carbon/src/Carbon/Carbon     .php:414
```

I believe in the first part of the stack trace,

`Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', Object(Carbon\Carbon))`

indicates that the second parameter must be a Carbon object, so you may have to make sure that is the case on the form rather than just `date('Y-m-d')` as you would in PHP.

Answer (score 1):

I am following Laracast tutorial, I encountered the same error. I finally figured out what is wrong with this exception.

In the function:

```
public function setPublishedAtAttribute($date)
{
    $this->attributes['published_at'] = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $date);
}
```

Noticed that my format for $date is **'Y-m-d'**

However, in my create.blade.php and edit.blade.php, the form input is:

```
{!! Form::input('data-date', 'published_at', date('d-m-Y'), ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
```

Noticed that my date format is **'d-m-Y'**.

This is the reason why the exception is thrown by Laravel.

After I made the date format the same as **'Y-m-d'** across all files, the exception disappears. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You will get this error if the database is returning a date value with a decimal microtime like this:

`2016-10-06 20:16:23.96034`

Those extra decimal digits are the problem. Remove those and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Working with dates that include the trailing timezone data is corrected by removing that trailing data using an Eloquent accessor:

```
public function getTimestampColumnAttribute()
{
    return Carbon::createFromFormat($this->dateFormat, strtok($this->attributes['timestamp_column'], '.'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I always has this problem because environments handler dates in different ways.
I Just stopped trailing date with carbon with this..

`public function getDates()
{
  return [];
}`

Answer (score 0):

Just Use in model

```
protected $dateFormat = ' H:i:s.Y-m-du';
```

or else

```
 public function getDateFormat()
 {
     return 'Y-m-d H:i:s.u';
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

Just remove this function:

```
public function setPublishedAtAttribute($date){
    $this->attributes['published_at']=Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d',$date);
}
```

becuase that fix the format for published_at field already...

Answer (score -4):

Just download the carbon source file and replace into the vendor's carbon directory. That's it...
https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon/releases