# Laravel model Trailing Data when save the model

Tags: php, laravel-5, model, trailing, invalidargumentexception

I have some code like this

```
    $editStuState = StuAtt::where('studentId' , '=' , $id)->first();
    $editStuState -> leave +=1;
    $editStuState -> present = $editStuState -> present-1;
    $editStuState->update();
                            //OR
    $editStuState->save();
    return 'this is good';
```

I can't save or Update my data,
when I remove Update and Save related line it can print text.

this is the `dd($editStuState)` data

```
StuAtt {#382 ▼
  #table: "stu_attendance"
  #connection: "mysql"
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  +incrementing: true
  #with: []
  #withCount: []
  #perPage: 15
  +exists: true
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  #attributes: array:7 [▼
    "id" => "7"
    "studentId" => "1"
    "present" => "2"
    "absent" => "1"
    "leave" => "10"
    "created_at" => "2018-04-16 11:17:41.176898"
    "updated_at" => "2018-04-16 06:47:41.000000"
  ]
  #original: array:7 [▼
    "id" => "7"
    "studentId" => "1"
    "present" => "2"
    "absent" => "1"
    "leave" => "10"
    "created_at" => "2018-04-16 11:17:41.176898"
    "updated_at" => "2018-04-16 06:47:41.000000"
  ]
  #changes: []
  #casts: []
  #dates: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #appends: []
  #dispatchesEvents: []
  #observables: []
  #relations: []
  #touches: []
  +timestamps: true
  #hidden: []
  #visible: []
  #fillable: []
  #guarded: array:1 [▶]
}
```

I also got this error form laravel 5.6 it

```
InvalidArgumentException
Trailing data
```

Answer (score 8):

If you are using Postgres you have to add some lines to your Model(s). It happens because of TIME WITH TIMEZONE in Postgres.

Please also read `Date Mutators` as Laravel already has support for this baked in, simply put below line in your Model to override the default dateFormat for that model: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators

Go to your App/Model (under `app` folder, exp. User, SomeModel) add below line:

```
protected $dateFormat = 'Y-m-d H:i:sO';
```

Best

Answer (score 1):

Change your code, from:

```
$editStuState = StuAtt::where('studentId' , '=' , $id)->first();
$editStuState -> leave +=1;
$editStuState -> present = $editStuState -> present-1;
$editStuState->update();
                        //OR
$editStuState->save();
return 'this is good';
```

To:

```
$editStuState = StuAtt::where('studentId' , '=' , $id)->first();
$editStuState -> leave +=1;
$editStuState -> present = $editStuState -> present-1;
$editStuState->save();
return 'this is good';
```

Method *->update(...)* is used for mass updates, check [Mass Updates](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#updates)

Comment: I say that I check both of them and get same errors.Do you see //OR?

Comment: Try adding *protected $dateFormat = 'Y-m-d H:i:s';* to your model

Answer (score 1):

If your Database is Postgres and your field is Timestamp sometimes Carbon cannot convert to default format (without milliseconds).

If milliseconds is not needed, update field content to not have the millisecond part.

```
UPDATE YOURTABLE SET created_at = date_trunc('seconds', created_at),
updated_at = date_trunc('seconds', updated_at)
```

This will normalize timestamped fields without milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, but I changed the column name to `creation_date` , the problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

In my case problem was length of `created_at` and `updated_at`in table. In Navicat table design was like this:

[image]

Change it to 0 and save changes:

[image]