# Laravel Eloquent Carbon Error Trailing Data at Postgresql Timestamp Format with millisecond

Tags: laravel, postgresql, eloquent, timestamp, php-carbon

I am using Laravel 5.7 and Postgresql for the database. Got the problem with eloquent error: carbon trailing data, caused by row data which has created_at/updated_at with millisecond on it.

I have tried this solution from another thread:
[Laravel model Trailing Data when save the model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50208932/laravel-model-trailing-data-when-save-the-model)
But got error, "Data missing".

Here is one sample of model which has created_at/updated_at field:

```
class Department extends Model
{
    /**
     * The table associated with the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'hr_department';

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'message_main_attachment_id',
        'name',
        'complete_name',
        'active',
        'company_id',
        'parent_id',
        'manager_id',
        'note',
        'color',
        'create_uid',
        'create_date',
        'write_uid',
        'write_date',
    ];

    const CREATED_AT = 'create_date';
    const UPDATED_AT = 'write_date';

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'create_date' => 'datetime',
        'write_date' => 'datetime',
    ];

    public function DepartmentParent() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Department', 'parent_id');
    }

    public function getDepartmentParentNameAttribute() {
        if ($this->DepartmentParent) {
            return $this->attributes['department_parent_name'] = $this->DepartmentParent->name;
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

The action in controller to show json result for api:

```
/**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function list(Request $request)
    {
        $httpCode = 200;
        $message = "Here is the department list";
        $modelData = null;

        try {
            $query = Department::whereRaw('0 = 0');
            if ($request->active)
                $query = $query->where('active', $request->active);
            if ($request->name)
                $query = $query->where('name', $request->name);
            $query = $this->setRestFilter($query, $request);
            $modelData = $query->get();
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $httpCode = $e->getCode();
            $message = $e->getMessage();
        }

        return response()->json([
            'message' => $message,
            'modelData' => $modelData
        ], $httpCode);
    }
```

Is there any configuration so the carbon does not read the millisecond from database? Or need to prevent laravel from saving the millisecond at created_at/updated_at field? And how to do that globally?

Comment: What does the migration look like?

Comment: do you mean the table structure?

Comment: Yes, the table structure.